# Crop images - OK for png - NOT OK for jpg

Tags: graphics, crop

In my `.tex` file I use heavily images that are usually cropped. They way I do this is like the following example:

```
\includegraphics[trim=52mm 20mm 30mm 10mm, clip=true, height=0.7 \textwidth]{img.png}
```

I ended up having ~160MB of `png` images, so I would like to convert them to `jpg` images for uploading to Arxiv (there is a space limit).

However after conversion to `jpg` cropping doesn't work anymore, i.e. there is no cropping, and I cannot find why this happens as well as a solution to this. The above example in this case looks like

```
\includegraphics[trim=52mm 20mm 30mm 10mm, clip=true, height=0.7 \textwidth]{img.jpg}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does `does not work any more` mean? Are the crop margins wrong? Is there no cropping at all?

Comment: There is no cropping at all, I edited my original message to clarify this

Comment: I guess your final document is really big at this point, but I would try making an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) out if. If it works there, you know there is something about a package or something else in your final document causing it. You could then try to add in your code from the preamble, say half of it first, and keep adding/removing until you locate the error. If that doesn't work with your MWE, it must be something about the jpg-encoding, odd, but could possibly happen. We need more info.

Comment: I did a MWE, kicking out everything (text, other images, commands, packages) and the issue is still the same. Cropping works for PNGs, but there is no cropping for JPGs. The image does appear in the pdf, it's only the cropping that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the JPEG files have a different resolution/size than the PNG files. Then different `trim` values would be needed.

Comment: Or maybe the jpg "lose" the `dpi` information, so that the graphics package is unable to map the dimensions to pixels.

Comment: runartrollet, actually you were right. After making sure that there is no package conflict with a MWE, I converted PNGs to JPGs with `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` and `mogrify -format jpg *.png`, instead of using MATLAB. It now works as expected, so the issue was indeed and surprisingly enough something with jpg encoding! (the resolution of png/jpg images was always the same)